Booting live usb with ubuntu
I am trying to install ubuntu desktop on my 10 years old computer that has windows 10 installed with the use of a live usb stick made by rufus.
When I try to boot my computer onto that usb the following message appears : "Grub Loading, Welcome to Grub!" but after waiting 30 minutes nothing happens.
How can I fix this ?

What checks did you perform?  Did you validate ISO after download?  Did you ensure the write of ISO to media was perfect (ie. compare type tool?) or boot & confirm that on another device?  FYI:  The oldest device I use in QA (Quality Assurance testing) is a 2005 HP Compaq; ie. a lot older than yours, but devices can be unique with unique issues.  (FYI:  Some BIOSes have bugs that cause the boot to be very slow; ie. >12 mins, so did you wait long enough?  This issue only impacts booting live media and not the system once installed)

The usb I used, works fine, I will try to wait long enough and try to see if it changed anything. I contact you soon

This question is similar to: Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It isnt the same issue as I have, please read the edited question

Your computer doesn't boot from Rufus. For cases such as this one Canonical makes the Ubuntu minimal USB. Instead of complaining about Rufus Canonical did something about it.
